# How to Impute using Simple Decision Tree in Python Script in Orange Data Mining?

Tags: orange

in Impute widget, there is option "Model-based(simple tree)" for imputation method

[image]

How to do this in Python Script Widget ?

from this documentation (https://docs.orange.biolab.si/3/data-mining-library/reference/preprocess.html#feature-selection) , i know how to Impute

```
from Orange.data import Table
from Orange.preprocess import Impute, Average

data = Table("heart_disease.tab")
imputer = Impute(method=Average())
impute_heart = imputer(data)
```

but the code is for Average method , i need Model-based (simple tree) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By analogy, even though a tad more complicated:

```
from Orange.data import Table
from Orange.preprocess import Impute, Model
from Orange.modelling import TreeLearner

data = Table("heart_disease.tab")
imputer = Impute(method=Model(TreeLearner()))
impute_heart = imputer(data)
```